# AngularJS + Jasmine: How to fulfill $promise using $httpBackend?

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller:

```
app.controller('ProductsIndexCtrl', ['$scope', 'ColorGroup', 'Shape', 'Material', function($scope, ColorGroup, Shape, Material) {

  ColorGroup.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
    $scope.color_groups = data;
  });
```

a factory:

```
app.factory('ColorGroup', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource("/api/color_groups", {}, {
    query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
  });
}]);
```

And a failing spec:

```
describe('mysite', function() {
  var scope, ProductsIndexCtrl;
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('mysite');
  });

  describe('ProductsIndexCtrl', function() {
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $injector) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();

      $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
      $httpBackend.when('/api/color_groups').respond([{"id":1,"name":"Browns","created_at":"2014-08-06T21:38:41.000Z","updated_at":"2014-08-06T21:38:41.000Z"},{"id":2,"name":"Blues","created_at":"2014-08-06T21:38:53.000Z","updated_at":"2014-08-06T21:38:53.000Z"},{"id":3,"name":"Greens","created_at":"2014-08-06T21:39:03.000Z","updated_at":"2014-08-06T21:39:03.000Z"}])

      ProductsIndexCtrl = $controller('ProductsIndexCtrl', {
        '$scope': scope
      });
    }));

    it('sets color_groups', function() {
      $httpBackend.flush();
      expect(scope.color_groups).toBeDefined(); // <-- fails
    });




  });

});
```

The failure is: `Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/color_groups`

I'm trying to test that the color_groups variable is defined on scope once the controller is instantiated. How would I do this?

Comment: Are you using angular-mocks.js?

Comment: nope How would I use that? I've heard of it. It's available but I don't know how to use it

Comment: Alright, you will need that. Located here: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/, grab angular-mocks.js. Second question, are you using node.js? Guessing the answer is yes since you are using karma..

Comment: You can add following to see if your requests have been fulfilled.   afterEach(function () {
            $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
            $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
        });